# Vibrating pipes on closed system

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair

I have a Gledhill pressurised system and it has started to vibrate when the cistern and pressure valve was changed after failing through the winter. 
I have had 3 different plumbers in and they don’t really know. 
It happens when the hot water is being used. The pressure is initially good and then sort pf settles but between those 2 events, that’s where the vibration occurs. All my taps are mostly mixers. 
I have watched it happen and the vibration occurs between the hot water pipe (taking hot water from the cylinder) to the white cistern which I believe is the overflow?! 
Both cistern and pressure valve (in red) have been checked and all fine.
Yet, still vibrating!
See photos.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Are we talking water hammer?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right